# Github shows another commiter name than my username

Tags: git, github

[image: Unknow user's commit]

Hello, I have created a repo in vscode and linked my local repo with github and whenever i commit in my project and push those commits to github, it shows someone with name pp123456 have commited, but not my github username. Why is this happening ? pls help me. My github username is Crystal-99.
If you see in my profile , whatever repos are present all are commited by this pp123456 but not Crystal-99. Please help.

Comment: Have you looked at your Git name in your local configuration?

Comment: you mean we see with the command git config --global user.name ? , yeah i checked that and it isnt this.

Comment: Also check local (not global) config: `git config user.name`.

Comment: even the local or global names are not this name. What to do?

Comment: https://docs.github.com/en/github/committing-changes-to-your-project/troubleshooting-commits/why-are-my-commits-linked-to-the-wrong-user

Comment: I have cloned two your repositories. The [first](https://github.com/Crystal-99/New/commits) one has commits authored by `Author: Rahul <rahulvenkatasai@gmail.com>`. The [second](https://github.com/Crystal-99/Product_sale/commits) one has author `sai_rahul <rahul@gmail.com>`. Github show username based on email, check `git config user.email`.

Answer (score 2):

Github shows username based on author's email. Check both local and global emails:

```sh
git config --global user.email
git config --local user.email
```

I've checked your repositories on Github, the email addresses are different for different repositories.

To set new local values:

```sh
git config --local user.name "your name here"
git config --local user.email "your email here"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also edit your git user name in .gitconfig file.

You can find the file in : C:\Users\Your_User --> .gitconfig file change your name
and email id and save it.